# Having class object as a member instead of inheriting the class

Tags: php, class, oop, object, inheritance

I am working on a project in which I have an `Order class` that represents a customer's order.

It has functions to manage the order (like change status) and to get details of the order (like invoice details)

I am creating a bunch of classes that will transfer the order to our various partners.

So I have classes like:

```
class PartnerXOrder extends Order
class PartnerYOrder extends Order
```

During peer review, a colleague suggested that I should not extend Order and instead have it as a class member:

```
Class PartnerXOrder
{
   private $orderObj;
   function __construct()
   {
      $this->orderObj = new Order();
   } 
}
```

Though we did discuss it a bit, I did not quite understand what advantage this approach has over extending the class. One, obviously, is in case the partner classes need to extend another class in the future - but that is not likely at all based on our current architecture.

Can anyone shed light on this? - or is my colleague just wrong?

Comment: Well, *is* your `PartnerXOrder` class *a* `Order`? Does it belong in the same hierarchy? Can `Order`s be substituted for `PartnerXOrder`s in certain (or all) cases? Or are you simply extending the class for convenience?

Comment: @deceze - `PartnerXOrder` has a bunch of functions for transferring the order to `PartnerX`...So technically -`Order` is the actual customer order details. And `PartnerXOrder` is additional functionality added to Order to facilitate the transfer - which is why I thought extending makes sense.

Comment: Ask yourself whether you'd ever use a `PartnerXOrder` **instead of** an `Order`. Would you ever pass an instance of `PartnerXOrder` to a `function (Order $order)`? Or are these two completely different functions which require two completely different types?

Answer (score 2):

> I am creating a bunch of classes that **will transfer** the order to our various partners.

Your colleague is right.
Basically, to answer the question *Should my class inherit this one?*, ask yourself: *Is my class `Y` a `X`?* (where `X` is the name of your parent class).

In your case, is `PartnerXOrder` an `Order`? As you said, no: its purpose is to transfer an `Order` to a `Partner`.

Comment: But by how OOPs works, isnt that what inheritance is for? It is "extending" the functionality of parent class for a specific purpose...

Comment: Inheritance is a "is-a relationship". So if `PartnerXOrder` is an `Order`, use inheritance. Otherwise, don't.